# Application name different CLI vs. Graphic Folder name // HandBrake

Tags: command-line

I have a quick question -- I just installed handBrake.

However when I open it in terminal I need to type 
$  ghb .

when I go to Graphic File Browser 
/usr/share/applications/
there is application called handbrake which is what I want and if I doulbe click on the icon it opens HandBrake just like when I type $ ghb.

When I go to HandBrake Properties under COMMAND: it shows "ghb".

My question is 
what can I do in the terminal to change "ghb" to "handbrake"
so that next time when I open the terminal and type $  handbrake the program will open?

Answer (score 3):

The most simple way is to create a symlink.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/ghb /usr/local/bin/handbrake
```

Other options include making a script to run it (either globally or in `~/bin/`), adding a bash alias or just learning that HandBrake's command is `ghb` :P

Comment: AWESOME DUDE!!! it works perfectly!!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! haha lol I should remember just type ghb haha lol :D thank you!!!!!!!!